# How to put files inside files

Tags: file-io

MS Word's .docx files contain a bunch of .xml files.

Setup.exe files spit out hundreds of files that a program uses.

Zips, rars etc also hold lots of compressed stuff.

So how are they made? What does MS Word or another program that produces these files have to do to put files inside files?

When I looked this up I just got a bunch of results about compression, but let's say I wanted to make a program that 'wraps' files inside a file without making the final result any smaller. What would I even have to write?

I'm not asking/expecting any source code that does this, I just need a pointer. Is there something you think I'm misunderstanding based on what I've asked here?

Even a simple link to an article or some documentation would be greatly appreciated.

## Ok, I'll just come up with some headers for ordinary files and write them along with the bytes of the actual files into one custom-defined file. You guys were very helpful, thank you!

Comment: A tar archive has a fairly simple structure, and is independent of the compression method used. Perhaps [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) could help you; it has a description of how files are stored in the archive.

Comment: why not just try and write a program that slams a bunch of files together and then another program that rips them apart?  It's not complicated to imagine this.  When you've had a go read the stuff about tar mentioned above or look at some source code in a language you understand for a file archiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Historically, Windows had a number of technologies to support solutions like this. These were often called Compound Files or Structured storage. However, I don't think the newer Office documents use these technologies. I think the Office file formats are similar to ZIP files with a different extensions. If you change a file with .docx extension to .zip and open it with your favorite compression tool, you'll see a bunch of folders and XML files.

Here are some links to descriptions of different file formats that create "files within files"

- [Zip file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format))
- [Compound File Binary Format (CFBF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_File_Binary_Format%20COM)
- [Structured Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage%20Microsoft)
- [Compound Document File Format](http://www.openoffice.org/sc/compdocfileformat.pdf)
- [Office Open XML I: Exploring the Office Open XML Formats](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Office-Open-XML-I-Exploring-the-Office-Open-XML-Formats-99e39a4d-0a20-4543-934d-55896e0b93ef)

Answer (score -1):

At least on POSIX systems (e.g. Linux), a file is only a stream (i.e. a sequence) of bytes. And you can only grow (or shrink, i.e. truncate) it at the end - there is no way to insert bytes in the middle (without copying the rest).

You need some conventions, and some additional software, to handle it otherwise.

You might be interested in [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), which gives you a library to handle some (e.g.) `*.sqlite`  file as an SQL database

You could also use [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/manual/gdbm.html) - a library giving you some indexed file abstraction.

[libtar](http://www.feep.net/libtar/) is a library to manipulate `tar` archives. See also [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/), a `tar` file postprocessor.